# I do have a certain experience with this

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is the highlighted part natural in the context?

Woman - Is he going to be okay?

Veterinarian - Yes, your dog will be fine.

Woman - Are you sure?

Veterinarian - Yes. **Trust me, miss, I do have a certain experience with this.**

Answer (score 1):

This reads as if the vet is being humble or perhaps ironic.  The vet is, we assume, an expert in animal health, and the woman is doubting his/her ability to diagnose the dog's condition.

He seems to be ironically saying "I have some experience with animals" to mean "I have a great deal of experience with animals, (and so you shouldn't doubt me)" It may be humble, but I think there is irony there. (the type of irony is "litotes": ironic understatement)

The literal meaning of "a certain experience" is "a certain level of experience". It can be inferred to mean "some experience" (but not a lot)

Answer (score 0):

It's natural except for the words *a certain experience*: when *experience* is used as a countable, it generally has the meaning of "a particular event of sensation that has been experienced". For the sense you want, it is generally uncountable:

> Trust me, miss, I do have some experience with this.

Or *I do have experience* or *I do have relevant experience*.